# How to accelerate opening an application

Tags: process-priority

I want to be able to open an app faster than the normal time it takes to open it. What kind of script of changes do I have to do to make it so that when the app starts to open it receives more priority in CPU and more resources to help open it quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try preload and zram.

### preload

Preload applications in memory - the next time you run the same app it'll open faster:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

### zram

Compressed swap in ram - zram: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
```

..and restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Preload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/preload/). This is a daemon that will pay attention to what applications you use most frequently and load them into memory at startup, which can greatly improve load times. You can [install it](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/preload) from the archives.

Answer (score 0):

Crude answer till you get better ones:

```
my_pid=$(ps -e | grep firefox | head -c 5 | tail -c 4)
```

gives the PID of the process

```
renice -1 $my_pid
```

would increase the renice

you can put this in an infinite loop using

sleep 60s

Comment: Two things: 1) you need a *negative* nice value, not positive; 2) rather than renicing multiple times after launch, how about launching the process with the desired 'nice' value from the beginning, as in `nice -n -10 firefox`? Of course you would need the permissions to do that, probably adjustable under `/etc/security/limits*`.

Comment: I agree. But, I assumed that the process was already on. For instance, if a user is into programming and his a.out pops out randomly; such a code would probably be good before starting out the programming session. Further, if necessary, one could use alias mod_firefox = 'nice -n -10 firefox' with the necessary permissions as you suggested.