# What size should my root partition be if I'd to use like a separate /home partition?

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

I thought a basic layout would call for 3 partitions on the 160 GB hdd of my EEE netbook. It's got 1 GB RAM so I'll go with a swap partition the same size. The question is what size my / partition should be. I'd like to allocate the rest to the /home partition.

I was told it neither matters if those are primary or logical nor if they're at the beginning or end of the disk. Can you second that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made mine about 15GB and have barely used over 9.  I think (if you plan on using hibernate) you may want to bump your swap to 2GB to be safer.

As for location, I put / at the beginning, though I haven't seen any huge benefit from it

Comment: Yep, if you need hibernation, memory and swap must have the same size (or more swap). For memory up to 1GB, it's good to have swap 2GB. For bigger memory size, just leave it up to 2GB, unless you need hibernate, as mentioned previously. **Tip**: When you set up your system, check out ways to make it a bit faster: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102816/how-to-accelerate-opening-an-application

Comment: What about primary and logical? And would you recommend using any more partitions?